# how to folder sort out by time php

Tags: php, directory, subdirectory

how to folder sortout by time example i create last/latest folder in directory so last folder show on top.

here is code to show directory only

```
<?php

function folderlist(){
  $startdir = './';
  $ignoredDirectory[] = '.'; 
  $ignoredDirectory[] = '..';
   if (is_dir($startdir)){
       if ($dh = opendir($startdir)){
           while (($folder = readdir($dh)) !== false){
               if (!(array_search($folder,$ignoredDirectory) > -1)){
                 if (filetype($startdir . $folder) == "dir"){
                       $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['name'] = $folder;
                       $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['path'] = $startdir;
                   }
               }
           }
           closedir($dh);
       }
   }
return($directorylist);
}


$folders = folderlist();
    foreach ($folders as $folder){
    $path = $folder['path'];
    $name = $folder['name'];

echo '<li><a href="' .$path .'index.php?album=' .$name . '" class="style1"><font face="Tahoma" class="ws10"><B>' . $name . '</B></a><br /></li>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you'll need to first grab the created time for the folder, and add that as the start of the key for the array item, then you'll be able to sort based on the key... something like this

```
<?php
function folderlist(){
  $directorylist = array();
  $startdir = './';
  $ignoredDirectory[] = '.';
  $ignoredDirectory[] = '..';
   if (is_dir($startdir)){
       if ($dh = opendir($startdir)){
           while (($folder = readdir($dh)) !== false){
               if (!(array_search($folder,$ignoredDirectory) > -1)){
                 if (filetype($startdir . $folder) == "dir"){
                       $created = filectime($startdir . $folder);
                       $directorylist[$created . $startdir . $folder]['name'] = $folder;
                       $directorylist[$created . $startdir . $folder]['path'] = $startdir;
                   }
               }
           }
           closedir($dh);
       }
   }

  ksort($directorylist);
  return($directorylist);
}


$folders = folderlist();

$total_files = 0;
foreach ($folders as $folder){
    $path = $folder['path'];
    $name = $folder['name'];
    $count = iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator($path . $name));
    $total_files += $count;

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' .$path .'index.php?album=' .$name . '" class="style1">';
    echo '<strong>' . $name . '</strong>';
    echo ' (' . $count . ' files found)';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
  echo "Total Files:". $total_files;
?>
```

Note the new $created variable in use, and also the ksort() method being used to sort the array by its key.

You could sort in reverse order ising krsort.

You could also change the ordering to be based on the modified date, by using filemtime() instead of filectime()

Comment: dear your code is showing noraml result nothng change in it i created a folder in a directory but folder is not show on the top and my folder is blank no files in my folder but this code show 2 file founds